# write part of xml file to new file, elementree

Tags: python, xml

I am parsing an xml file: http://pastebin.com/fw151jQN I wish to read it in and copy some of it to a new file. I'm not sure how easy that is? I can currently copy the whole file with this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('interface_range_test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
tree.write('new_file.xml', encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

Is there a way to search and write certain elements to a new file?

Initially I want to create a new file that just contains the following as a test run:

```
<COMMAND name="shutdown"
        help="Shutdown the selected interface">
        <CONFIG priority="0x7F01" />
        <ACTION>
        /klas/klish-scripts/interfaces.py conf -i ${iface} --enable 0
        </ACTION>
    </COMMAND>

    <COMMAND name="no shutdown"
        help="Enable the selected interface">
        <CONFIG operation="unset" pattern="shutdown"/>
        <ACTION>
        /klas/klish-scripts/interfaces.py conf -i ${iface} --enable 1
        </ACTION>
    </COMMAND>
```

Another way might be to isolate the necessary information and form elements from it? Here is my attempt to isolate the xml above:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('interface_range_test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
namespaces = {'command': 'http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND','config': 'http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}CONFIG'}

commands = root.findall(".//{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND")

for command in commands:
    subs = command.findall('.//{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}CONFIG')
    action = command.findall('.//{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}ACTION')

    if len(subs) > 0: #we found CONFIG
        print command.tag
        #print command.attrib['name']
        #print command.attrib.keys(),command.attrib.values()
        b = command.attrib.items()
        print b
        print subs[0].tag
        c = subs[0].attrib.items()
        print c
    if len(action) > 0: #we found ACTION
        print action[0].tag
        print action[0].attrib
        print action[0].text
```

This gets all the relevant information but also gets some extra action tags and their text.

```
{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}ACTION
{'builtin': 'clish_nested_up'}
None
{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}ACTION
{}

/klas/klish-scripts/ifrange.py validate_range --range "${interface_method} ${iface_num} ${range_separator} ${iface_num2}  ${range_separator2} ${interface_method2} ${iface_num3} ${range_separator3} ${iface_num4} ${range_separator4} ${interface_method3} ${iface_num5} ${range_separator5} ${iface_num6} ${range_separator6} ${interface_method4} ${iface_num7} ${range_separator7} ${iface_num8}"

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
/klas/klish-scripts/ifrange.py run_command --cmdrange "${interface_method} ${iface_num} ${range_separator} ${iface_num2}  ${range_separator2} ${interface_method2} ${iface_num3} ${range_separator3} ${iface_num4} ${range_separator4} ${interface_method3} ${iface_num5} ${range_separator5} ${iface_num6} ${range_separator6} ${interface_method4} ${iface_num7} ${range_separator7} ${iface_num8}" --command "/klas/klish-scripts/interfaces.py conf -i {iface} --enable 0" --klish_config "shutdown" --klish_action "set" --priority "0x7F01"
fi





{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND
[('name', 'shutdown'), ('help', 'Shutdown the selected interface')]
{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}CONFIG
[('priority', '0x7F01')]
{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}ACTION
{}

        /klas/klish-scripts/interfaces.py conf -i ${iface} --enable 0

{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND
[('name', 'no shutdown'), ('help', 'Enable the selected interface')]
{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}CONFIG
[('pattern', 'shutdown'), ('operation', 'unset')]
{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}ACTION
{}

        /klas/klish-scripts/interfaces.py conf -i ${iface} --enable 1
```

I could try and use the data found to create output? Is this a good way to do it? Or is there a better way than trying to search for each piece of data? Perhaps getting the node and then it's grandchildren? I can't seem to make that work however. Or finding the shutdown element and writing all of it and it's children to a file?

Can i write nodes like that?

EDIT to show changing the text

```
for command in commands:
    if 'shutdown' in command.get('name'):
        for i in command:
            i.text = "abc" #modify to taste

        ET.dump(command) # modify to taste
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You cannot get *exactly* the desired output from ElementTree, because you ask for a not well-formed XML. Either wrap `<COMMAND>` nodes into a root tag, or serialize fragments one by one and concatenate.

(2) Yes, there's a [reasonable implementation of search by XPath expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax). In your case you have to specify namespaces while searching. Plain scanning of elements under the root element might suffice, too.

My take:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('interface_range_test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
# note the explicit namespaces
commands = root.findall('{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}'
                        'VIEW/{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND')
for command in commands:
  if 'shutdown' in command.get('name'):
    ET.dump(command) # modify to taste
```

Comment: Great help thank you. When you say exactly the same output what do you mean? That output you generated seems fine and the format I want (I take it ns0 doesnt affect the file, why does it write that?) So basically I look for everything I want one by one and concatenate to a file? Since it says `dump` is for debug use only, how do I write command to a file? it says element has no write function. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to modify the text, but I dont know if this is a good way, edited it into my post. That seems ok now I just need to get it into a file.

Comment: @Paul: Reading [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) helps, for they tell you how to write a subtree to a string. From that point, you're [probably fine](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write).

Comment: Thanks I was trying to convert the element into an elementtree but getting errors, I'll try that way which is nice and simple.

Comment: @Paul, sorry to open back this issues but how did you successfully get through writing the data into a new xml file

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan Npo problem. I converted the XML elements to a string and then simply wrote that to a file using basic python. This should help you convert: for i in tree_list:
            cmd += ET.tostring(i[0], encoding="utf-8", method="xml")